# Exchange End User Usage Statistics Tools

Tags: exchange, monitoring, exchange-2007, audit

Anyone know of software/tools used to measure and draw reports based off of end user Exchange usage? Items for a particular user would include:

- How many messages a day
- List of top receipts from that user
- Collective KB/MB sent per day/week
- Peak times of usage

This is not so much about Anti-virus/spam, but basically a desire to find out how employees are using their corporate email accounts without directly attaching to their boxes and snooping around.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want an exchange tracking log analyzer.  I haven't found any I love and we actually use scripts to do our analysis at this point, but the good news is many of them allow free testing so you can try before you buy.